# Mockito many method call return value problem with Spring WebFlux unit test (on mono repeat)

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito, spring-webflux

I have following code for controller method

```
    @PostMapping("/{id}")
    public Mono<PacketResponse> info(@PathVariable String id, @RequestBody PacketRequest request) {
        log.info("step 2 - {}", id);

        // ask for data
        return dataService
                .getDataById(id).log().map(r -> {
                    log.info("step 2 - ... {}", id);
                    return new PacketResponse();
                })
                .repeatWhenEmpty(10, l -> l.delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(2)).map(c -> { log.info("{}", c); return c+1;}))
                ;
    }
```

This method tries to get data at most 10 times if empty.

I'm testing this method with the following unit test:

```
        Mockito
                .when(
                        dataService.getDataById(anyString())
                )
                .thenReturn(
                        Mono.empty(),
                        Mono.just(new PacketBean())
                )
        ;

        webTestClient
                .post().uri(String.format("/qrsign/%s", id))
                .body(Mono.just(new PacketRequest()), PacketRequest.class)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk()
                .expectBody(PacketInfoResponse.class).isEqualTo(new PacketInfoResponse());
```

But test never gives second value (non empty) for mocked service.

What can be a problem here?

Comment: use `Mono.defer(() -> dataService.getDataById(id))` in your production code, that will trigger a new service call for each repeat